# How can I solve this 2nd-order, non-linear, stiff ODE numerically using Matlab?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

I need to find a numerical solution for $T(x)$ to

\begin{equation}
aT'' - bT^4 + c = 0, \ \ \ T(0) = T_0, \ \ \  T'(L) = 0
\end{equation}
where $a$, $b$, $c$, $T_0$ and $L$ are positive constants. This is a heat conduction and emission problem with boundary conditions, and FYI we know that $T'(0)<0$.

The problem is stiff, and Mathematica is failing me.

What Matlab solver do I use? How do I find an equivalent system of first-order equations?

Comment: The equivalent system of first order equations is standard to write: $x=T,y=T'$, so $x'=y,y'=\frac{b}{a} x^4 - \frac{c}{a},x(0)=T_0,y(L)=0$. The problem is difficult because it is a BVP. The most likely Matlab functions to help you will be bvp4c or bvp5c, with the helper function bvpinit to construct the initial guess object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
b_over_a=1;
c_over_a=1;
T0=2;
L=1;
odefun=@(x,y) [y(2);b_over_a*y(1).^4-c_over_a];
bcfun=@(ya,yb) [ya(1)-T0;yb(2)];
solinit=bvpinit(linspace(0,L,1e2),[T0;0]);
sol=bvp4c(odefun,bcfun,solinit);
plot(sol.x,sol.y(1,:))
```

This plots the solution to your problem with $b/a=1,c/a=1,T_0=2,L=1$. It uses a constant initial guess i.e. $T(x)=2,T'(x)=0$, and uses an initial mesh with 100 evenly spaced points. It gives Matlab the option to extend this mesh, but in this particular case it decides not to do so.

Your problem might be stiffer than this one depending on the exact parameter values you are using, but the particular parameters that I chose appear to not be stiff at all.

For more details see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry, but I'm struggling to understand: where in this code does $T'(L)=0$ stand? Would you mind rewriting this code keeping `a, b, c, T0, L` as variables? How can I act upon the initial guesses if my problem becomes too stiff for different constant values?

Comment: @RegencyAndCo I revised to insert the dependence on the parameters more explicitly. $T'(L)=0$ is expressed in the fact that the second entry of the return from "bcfun" is yb(2). yb, when passed to bcfun, is y (the vector $(T,T')$) at the right endpoint. Thus yb(2) is $T'(L)$. Finally the solver ensures that bcfun(ya,yb) is the zero vector, so you enforce that yb(2) is zero (or very close to it, perhaps). As for the stiffness, it would really depend on what exactly is causing the stiffness, so I would need to have more specific parameter values to be sure.

Comment: @RegencyAndCo It would also depend on what you expect from the solution. For example, maybe you physically expect it to be decreasing and convex; this would tend to happen if $c/a$ is not too big relative to $b/a$ and $T_0$. Then you could try an initial guess which is quadratic, where the vertex at $L$, and the value at the left end is given by $T_0$. Then you have one remaining "tuning parameter" that you can adjust until you get convergence.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I get it now. Everything about BVP is just very confusing to me, and the documentation is a rabbit hole, so if you don't mind me asking: how do I input my quadratic function as an initial guess? do I need a guess for y(2)?

Comment: @RegencyAndCo This part of the documentation is actually quite clear: YINIT can be either a vector or a function handle: ... function:  YINIT is a function of a scalar x. For example, use 
               solinit = bvpinit(x,@yfun) if for any x in [a,b], yfun(x) 
               returns a guess for the solution y(x).

Comment: @RegencyAndCo So in this case you could use guess=@(x) T0+a\*x^2-2\*a\*L\*x where a>0 is the tuning parameter.

Comment: @RegencyAndCo (Sorry, my $a$ is different from your $a$...)

Comment: @RegencyAndCo Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake: the initial guess needs to include a guess for $T$ and for $T'$. But that's easy, just compute the derivative. So you can try guess=@(x) [T0+r\*x^2-2\*r\*L\*r;2\*r\*x-2\*r\*L] (where I've changed the name of the tuning parameter to $r$). A bonus: if $c/a$ is too big, this should still work nicely with $r<0$.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps,

$$aT'T'' +(c - bT^4)T' = 0$$

then

$$\frac a2T'^2+(cT-\frac b5T^5)=C.$$

Comment: I think this does actually help. Plugging in the BCs gives two equations in three unknown parameters ($T'(0),T(L)$, and $C$). So you can parametrize everything by, say, $C$, then plug the result back into the ODE to identify $C$.

Comment: In fact there can be a difficulty. Given $C $ and the sign of $T'(0) $ one can find $T'(0) $ and $cT (L)-bT (L)^5/5$ from your "conservation" equation. But this may not uniquely specify $T (L)$.